# Array lowercase

Tags: arrays, perl

I'm new to Perl and I've ran into a little problem. I'm trying to pick one value out of an array to make it lowercase.

E.g.

```
my @letters = qw(A B C D E F F A S D F E S F);
```

Now I want to pick the letter F and make it lowercase, how can I go about doing this? 
Keep in mind my array is very large and it should be able to take any changes made by the user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you knew to programming or to the syntax of the language?

Comment: I'm new to the programming, I've worked quite a lot with C#/PHP/Python/C++ but Perl seems to differ quite a lot from those syntax's.

Comment: `my @new = map { $_ eq "F" ? lc $_ : $_ } @letters;`

Comment: @squiguy `map{lc}grep{/F/}@letters` more readable I think

Comment: @loldop One less function call though.  TIMTOWTDI.

Comment: This is why I love Perl so much, you can answer to questions in the comments section =]

Comment: @Stasel yeah, you can put any stuff in one line :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for my $c (@letters) {$c = lc($c) if $c eq"F"}
```

I absolutely don't know what you mean by *pick* and *make it*.

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to look in the array @letters. I'm picking a value from it, "F" and I'm trying to lowercase that value.

Comment: @Toby: It's still not clear what you mean by "picking a value". Do you want to convert *all* occurrences of `"F"` to lowercase? The first occurrence? What exactly is your criterion for "picking"?

Comment: I still don't understand. What is input and what is output?

Comment: @Hynek Yes I want to convert each value in the array that is eq to "F" to lowercase. So the output should be: A B C D E f f A S D f E S f.

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach:

```
my @letters = qw(A B C D E F F A S D F E S F);
@letters = map { tr/F/f/; $_ } @letters;
```

**UPDATE**: as @TLP commented, this is a simpler way:

```
my @letters = qw(A B C D E F F A S D F E S F);
tr/F/f/ for @letters;
```

Comment: Redundant use of `map`. Use `tr/F/f/ for @letters` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Short inplace modification is

```
my @letters = qw(A B C D E F F A S D F E S F);
map {s/(F)/\l$1/;} @letters;
print "@letters";
```

Output:

```
 A B C D E f f A S D f E S f
```

Comment: When I look at `s/F/\l$&/;}` it just makes me glad I don't use Perl. :P

Comment: @Doorknob Not skilled at regexes?

Comment: That substitution hurts especially if you know Perl: Usage of `$&` and friends slows down *all* regex matches in your program. Using a capture `s/(F)/lc $1/e` is probably faster.

Comment: @TrueY so `Perlish` way to lc, hah

Comment: @amon `s/F/lc/e for @letters` perhaps.

Comment: Ok, what about this `map {s/(F)/\l$1/;} @letters;`. 
Personal comment: I usually avoid to use the e modifier as it is fairly new (for me) and not well documented (I always have to dig for it).

Comment: @TrueY "e" as in "evaluation". What's to document? Read `perldoc -f eval` if you have questions. You should avoid it because evaluation is evil, hack-ish and dangerous. Not because of lack of skill or documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to keep the orginal list

```
tr/F/f/ for @letters
```

Answer (score -1):

If you already know the location in the array, you would do: `$array[5] = lc($array[5])`. If you don't there are several ways. One of them uses C style looping:

```
for (my $i=0; $i < @array; $i++) {
  $array[$i] = lc($array[$i]) if $array[$i] eq 'F';
}
```

another is map:

```
map {$_ = lc if $_ eq 'F'} @array;
```